# Question about intuition of calculating probabilities with combinations and counting methods(e.g. probability of a full house)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, card-games

This is just a question to make sure I understand the intuition of using combinations to calculate probabilities from examples such as a deck of cards. Take for example finding the probability of a full house. Is the logic as follows, at the end of the day we are defining the probability as the number of hands/outcomes in the sample space that satisfy the desired condition(i.e. the total number of outcomes that give a full house), over the total number of outcomes/cardinality of the sample space itself? so instead of literally enumerating all possible outcomes, and then counting the total and counting all the possible combinations of full houses by hand, we can use the counting rules to do so?

When are there restrictions on this- can we use this definition of probability more broadly and then use counting tools or does it only apply to cases where the support is finite and each individual outcome equally likely?

Comment: As your own instincts have indicated, the best way of attacking this problem is to express the probability as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$$ where $N$ and $D$ must be expressed in a **consistent** manner.  That is, if $D$ is computed in terms of combinations, where the order that the cards are dealt is irrelevant, rather than permutations, then $N$ must be computed in a similar manner.

Comment: To use counting to give a probability, you need the individual events being counted in the denominator to be equally likely, and similarly for the subset being counted in the numerator.  You may also need to take care to avoid double counting some events.

Comment: As an illustrating example, suppose that you had all 4 Aces, but no other cards, and you were going to be dealt two of the 4 cards.  You might then ask what the probability is of receiving both red Aces.  You might calculate this as either $$\frac{1}{\binom{4}{2}}$$ or as $$\frac{2!}{4\times 3}.$$

Comment: "...or does it only apply to cases where the support is finite and each individual outcome equally likely?"  I have never seen the counting approach used where the denominator was not finite.  That is not to say that such a problem (with an infinite denominator) could not be validly attacked by counting.  Merely that I personally have never seen it.  As for the second portion of your excerpted question, see the prior comment of Henry.